# How to get duration of an access token?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-access-token

I think I have gotten a long duration page access token.  When I got the long token for my user, ( https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token ) it returns the token and the duration (60 days).  But when i get the user's pages using that token, I just get the page token, with no clue as to its duration.

I just want to check the page token and see what it's duration is, just a sanity check to know that I am doing things correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your access token directly in the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). Just insert your token and you should get the expiration time.

Comment: awesome: 
    Expires: Never
    Valid: True.  
Do you know how to $facebook->api() for that info?

Comment: It seems there should be a method for that info, but I don't think there is. Sry.

Comment: Well, unless someone comes along with an api call for this, this will be my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Page access tokens obtained by queries made using a:

- short-lived user access token are short-lived as well
- long-lived access token never expire.

The documentation you linked covers both of these cases:

> With the migration enabled, when using a short-lived user access token to query this endpoint, the page access tokens obtained are short-lived as well.
>
> ...
>
> By using a long-lived user access token, querying the `[User ID]/accounts` endpoint will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that a user manages.

Comment: Oh, 'do not expire' hmm.  I thought I was going to have to store the dates and do some cron to email the user (me) and remind to go refresh the token.  (I am posting to my page via my site, but triggered by site user, ie, I am not logged in at the time)

Comment: You should be able to infer the post access token life from the life of the access token used to query the `[User ID]/accounts` API endpoint.

Comment: hehe, ok hence my confusion: 'do not expire' vs. 'infer the post access token life'  -(and i think you meant 'page access token')

Comment: Whoops, sorry - yes! `s/post/page/`

Comment: From what I remember, long-lived access tokens do expire after 60 days.  (Will provide link with reference as soon as i can)